# Rigify, how do I make an additional visibility display toggle for bones?

Tags: rigging, rigify

When I turn on Rigify facial controls it fills the face with cubes and I wish I had a switch to only show/hide just the mouth controls, or just the eyelid controls, or just eyebrow controls? Without disabling the Rigify panel functionality to show/hide the 2 red and yellow facial groups.

How do I go about doing that?

I could change all the shapes for all the characters but I rather it be less cluttered.

Comment: I've not used Rigify much but can't you simply Shift-select all the controllers you want in one group in Pose mode then use M to move them to their own bone layer? Then just Shift-click the layer under the armature's Skeleton properties  to toggle its visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by John Eason, in pose mode you can select some bones, press M and move them to an empty bone layer, which can be turned on and off in the armature properties panel.

[image]

If you want to add the relative buttons in the UI, open a text editor window, from drop down menu choose the "rig_ui.py" text, scroll untill nearly the end, copy and paste the lines highlighted in green and change the orange values only (bone layers numbers and names)

The upper rows of bone layers are numbered 0-7 and 8-15, while the bottom layers are 16-23 and 24-31.

Be aware that you have to respect the indentations in the text, while you can insert empty lines as you want.

Press the triangle Play icon to run the script (or press Alt P).

Edit: you can select an empty line under the green highlighted, press Enter to create a new line, press Tab twice to indent at the correct location and paste these lines, then run the script:

row = col.row()

```
    row.prop(context.active_object.data, 'layers', index=19, toggle=True, text='Custom Face 01')


    row.prop(context.active_object.data, 'layers', index=20, toggle=True, text='Custom Face 02')

    
     row = col.row()


    row.prop(context.active_object.data, 'layers', index=21, toggle=True, text='Custom Face 03')


    row.prop(context.active_object.data, 'layers', index=22, toggle=True, text='Custom Face 04')
```

[image]

Comment: Ooo! That's useful! I guessed it could be done with Python but had no idea how you could do it.

Comment: It's ultra easy!

Comment: I'm sure it is if you've used python before... :^) Would it be possible to add the code as text to your answer instead of just an image of it?

Comment: I'm not a programmer, it' really easy as much as copy and paste, just respect the indentation eventually using the Tab key and don't touch the quote symbols. The complete code is quite big ....

Comment: Fair enough. I'd already removed the 'complete' from my previous comment.

Comment: @joshsanfelici Once I create the custom rig_ui.py for adding new buttons, if I paste to every subsequent rig_ui.py for other characters they would all have the extra buttons also... correct?

Comment: I'm not a Python Wizard, I guess that if the rig has a different name it needs to have a slightly different script, so I think it's safer to perform the edit on every new armature.